# How to update database connection for migration

Tags: laravel

I have post request where I update database config. I save data for one connection in my storage. In database config I call function to get it.

When data are updated I also update local config by 
`config('database.connections.myconnection',$newConf)`

The problem is in artisan:migrate action. In the same request I need to call to artisan:migrate but with new datbaase configuration.

Unfortunately I can set only database string to `Artisan::call('migrate',['database'=>'myconnection'])`

Migrate try to use old db data and I get error about db connection.

Someone have any idea how I can provide new config for migrate "in fly"?

Comment: Tags are there to tell others what the questions is about, not what the question contains. The questions seems not to be version specific and thus these questions are not necessary

Comment: @milo526 not exactly. Laravel has different solutions between version and in my opinion, set version it important. Please remember that before solve the problem I didn't be sure about version relation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you "also update local config", you don't really update it, because you config is in a file and the config helper doesn't write to file. You're just setting a default here. That being said...

If what you are saving to the database is the connection name (ex.: 'mysql', or 'default'), it could be as easy as sending the artisan call with the database name, with the config helper checking for a dynamic name.

```
Artisan::call('migrate',
    ['database' => config("database.connections.{$newConf}")
])
```

Comment: I wrote that I update my local config and this is true. After this operation and call again to config I see new values. 

I can't use your example because database must be string not array, artisan return exception

Comment: Thanks for hit. It should be

`
$newConnection = 'new';
      config(["database.connections.$newConnection" =>$newConfigArray]);
`
but in artisan should be string

`\Artisan::call('migrate',['--database'=>$newConnection,'--force'=>true]);`

Solved